# how to read strings with timer in JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to read strings in 2 minutes but in the end ListOfwords only gets the first word. Any suggestions?

```
 ArrayList<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
 String word;

  try{
    System.out.println("Guess words: ");    
    Thread.sleep(time*1000*120);
    word = in.next();
    listOfWords.add(word);
    System.out.println("Out of time!!!!!!\n");
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 System.out.println(listOfWords);
```

Comment: where are u reading the word twice? i see it only once!

Comment: omg you are right. i've tried a do while but when does the timer ends? when is equal to zero? it still reading just the first word.

Answer (score 0):

to use the `Timer` for scheduling a task(i.e. reading a string) try your code as below:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
            String word;
            System.out.println("Guess words: ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            word = in.next();
            listOfWords.add(word);
            System.out.println(word);
            System.out.println("Out of time!!!!!!\n");
        }
    }, 0, time);
```